# Await a future, receive an either

Tags: scala, future

I'd like to await a scala future that may have failed.  If I use `Await.result` the exception will be thrown.  Instead, if I have `f: Future[String]` I would like a method `Await.resultOpt(f): Option[String]` or `Await.resultEither(f): Either[String]`.

I could get this by using `scala.util.control.Exception.catching` or I could `f map (Right(_)) recover { case t: Throwable => Left(t) }`, but there must be a more straightforward way.

Comment: `Try` / `Success` / `Failure` are a lot nicer to deal with than `Either[Throwable, Value]`. IMO...

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You could use `Await.ready` which simply blocks until the Future has either succeeded or failed, then returns a reference back to that Future.

From there, you would probably want to get the Future's `value`, which is an `Option[Try[T]]`. Due to the `Await.ready` call, it should be safe to assume that the `value` is a `Some`. Then it's just a matter of mapping between a `Try[T]` and an `Either[Throwable, T]`.

The short version:

```
val f: Future[T] = ...

val result: Try[T] = Await.ready(f, Duration.Inf).value.get

val resultEither = result match {
  case Success(t) => Right(t)
  case Failure(e) => Left(e)
}
```

Comment: I think this is better solution:

`Await.ready(f, Duration.Inf).onComplete(result => {
          result match {
            case Success(t) => Right(t)
            case Failure(e) => Left(e)
          }
        })`

calling **get** on Option is generally a bad idea

Comment: @Klapsa2503 in most cases I would agree, but in this case it's perfectly fine; if `Await.ready` doesn't throw, the `value` will always be a `Some`. One is free to add the extra check for code quality reasons, but it should be technically unnecessary here.

Comment: @Dylan - why did you use `Await#ready` instead of `Await#result`?

Comment: @KevinMeredith because the OP specifically pointed out the issues with `Await.ready`, and asked for an alternative.

Comment: @KevinMeredith (whoops, meant "issues with Await.result")

Answer (score 3):

The shorter version, just to promote the API:

```
scala> val f = Future(7)
f: scala.concurrent.Future[Int] = scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise@13965637

scala> f.value.get
res0: scala.util.Try[Int] = Success(7)

scala> import scala.util._
import scala.util._

scala> Either.cond(res0.isSuccess, res0.get, res0.failed.get)
res2: scala.util.Either[Throwable,Int] = Right(7)

scala> val f = Future[Int](???)
f: scala.concurrent.Future[Int] = scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise@64c4c1

scala> val v = f.value.get
v: scala.util.Try[Int] = Failure(java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: Boxed Error)

scala> Either.cond(v.isSuccess, v.get, v.failed.get)
res4: scala.util.Either[Throwable,Int] = Left(java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: Boxed Error)
```

It has a slight advantage in being a one-liner.

But of course, after adding a `.toEither` extension method, you don't care how many lines it took.

Comment: This won't work if the Future hasn't finished yet. `f.value` will be None, so calling `f.value.get` will throw an Exception.

Comment: @Dylan I was just demonstrating `Either.cond` at res2. Obviously, one must wait for it. Edit: oh, you're that Dylan. Yes, your match is fine, this is a one-liner, not necessarily perspicacious. Edit again: perspicacity doesn't matter either if you pimped it.

Answer (score 1):

You could start to make your own type utils and do something like so

```
  trait RichTypes {

    import scala.util.{Try, Success, Failure}
    import scala.concurrent.{Await, Future}
    import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration

    implicit class RichFuture[T](f: Future[T]) {
      def awaitResult(d: Duration): Either[Throwable, T] = {
        Try(Await.result(f, d)).toEither
      }
    }

    implicit class RichTry[T](tri: Try[T]) {
      def toEither(): Either[Throwable, T] = {
        tri.fold[Either[Throwable, T]](Left(_), Right(_))
      }
    }
  }

  object Example
    extends App
      with RichTypes {

    import scala.concurrent.Future
    import scala.concurrent.duration._

    val succ = Future.successful("hi").awaitResult(5.seconds)
    val fail = Future.failed(new Exception("x")).awaitResult(5.seconds)

    println(succ) // Right(hi)
    println(fail) // Left(Exception(x))
  }
```

I separated it out for a `Try` to also have a `.fold` :).