# Either wait for a function to finish or timeout after 5 seconds in Akka

Tags: scala, akka

I'm trying to wait for a function to finish or timeout after 5 seconds, but whatever I do, I can't prevent the following exception. Interestingly it is caught by the parent actor:

```
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [5 seconds]
```

One of the solutions that I tried (from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21417317/await-a-future-receive-an-either) question):

```
val f = Future { dockerClient.execStartCmd(execCreateCmdResponse.getId()).exec() }
val result: Try[InputStream] = Await.ready(f, 5.seconds).value.get

val resultEither = result match {
  case Success(t) => log.info("right")
  case Failure(e) => log.info("left")
}
```

Comment: Have you seen all the other options? `Await` is blocking and evil... 
http://semberal.github.io/scala-future-timeout-patterns.html

Comment: @AndreyTyukin thank you for the article. I solved it using the ask pattern.

Comment: What does one usually do with this kind of "answers"? Close the question so that noone can capitalize on semberal's knowledge?

Comment: @AndreyTyukin either leave it as it is or add a simple usage of the ask pattern as an answer saying how it solves the problem with a link to semberal's article for detailed information. This is a simplified version of my code; you can use it in if you want: http://pastebin.com/LXPpgWeS

Comment: @AndreyTyukin Or we can create a wiki-type post about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed it's possible to achieve this with akka ask pattern. But there is a different solution that can be used without akka.

Wrap your blocking `Await` code into another `Future` and register `onComplete` function

```
import concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.concurrent.{Await, Future}
import scala.util.{Failure, Success, Try}

val sleepTimeout = 1*1000

val f = Future( Thread.sleep(sleepTimeout); Try(10))
val timeoutFuture = Future(Await.result(f, 5.seconds))
timeoutFuture.onComplete {
  case Success(Success(t))  => println(t)
  case Success(Failure(ex))  => println("error on Try" + ex.getMessage)
  case Failure(e) => println("timeout " + e.getMessage)
}
```

Explaining match cases

- `Success(Success(t))` First `Success` is for the `timeoutFuture`, it means it did not timeout. Second `Success` is for `Try` - means no exception were thrown.
- `Success(Failure(ex))` same as first but there is exception within `Try`
- `Failure(e)` this is where timeout is handled.

Comment: I don't suggest you to `Await` inside a `Future` because you block 2 threads this way. You need to implement timeout with a scheduler. Take a look at this: http://nami.me/2015/01/20/scala-futures-with-timeout/