# Usage scala Futures fallbackTo

Tags: scala

I'm trying to achieve something like this.

```
val x: SomeType = ...    
val future: Future[SomeType] = Future {
  /*
   * Do some operation on x
   */
  x
}
future onComplete {
  case Success (x): x.status = "Success";
  case Failure (t):
    /*
     *  Here I want to write x.status = "Failed", But
     *  x is not available in this scope
     */
}
```

What is the efficient way to achieve this?

Comment: 'case Failure' means that your code (inside 'Future{...}') has thrown an exception, so there is no way having x as it didn't returned (even if you use normal ways like fallBackTo, recover, recoverWith). Anyway I wouldn't recommend to use mutable data here. Your problem whatever it is can be solved without this.

Answer (score 0):

First, your code doesn't seem like correct Scala code. Case-Match is wrong, In `Future[x]`, you should mention the type as `x`, but return `x` itself, which should be an object.

Anyways, you could do something like done below. When the Future succeeds you can record the value in a `var`, and if it fails you can still record the value in a `var`. However that brings mutable state into your program which very soon goes out of control. So it is better to use idiomatic Scala code ( use map, flatMap, etc ), and avoid state altogether.

```
import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration
import scala.concurrent.{Await, Future}
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.util.Random

object TestFuture {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val future: Future[Int] = Future {
      if (Random.nextBoolean()) {
        10
      } else {
        throw new RuntimeException("Error")
      }
    }

//    future onComplete {
//      case Success(x) =>
//        println(x)
//      case Failure(t) =>
//        t.printStackTrace()
//    }

    future onSuccess {
      case x => println(s"SUCCESS: $x")
        // SUCCESS: 10
    }

    future onFailure {
      case x => println(s"FAILURE: $x")
        // FAILURE: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error
    }

    Await.ready(future, Duration.Inf)
  }

}
```

There is more than one way to do it.

Also check following :

- http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html
- [Await a future, receive an either](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21417317/await-a-future-receive-an-either)

Comment: Pardon me. Your first paragraph is what I meant, did not realize up until now. Updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking at it from a mutable/procedural point of view. It's better to use it like a Monad. You can do this instead:

```
case class Result(status: String)

val future: Future[Result] = Future { ... }

future map {
  result => result.copy(status = "Success")
} recover {
  case NonFatal(_) => Result("Failure")
}
```

This will always return a "successful" Future with correct status. No mutability is happening as well.

I didn't check if it compiles ;)