# How to block the thread and get Try[A] from Future[A]?

Tags: scala

I have `List[Future[A]]`. I'd like to block my thread and get `List[Try[A]]` "right now". Can't find a nice solution.

Comment: Do not block threads.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Await a future, receive an either](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21417317/await-a-future-receive-an-either)

Comment: "Right now" even if the futures didn't finish? Or you want to wait for the futures to finish?

Comment: Also what did you try so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that you have clarified your question (in the comment to my other answer), here's one possibility to do it:

```
import scala.util._
import scala.concurrent._

def partitionFutures[A](
  l: List[Future[A]])(
  implicit ec: ExecutionContext
): Future[(List[A], List[Throwable])] = {
  Future.traverse(l)(_.transform(Success.apply)).map { (trys: List[Try[A]]) =>
    val as = trys.collect { case Success(a) => a }
    val errs = trys.collect { case Failure(err) => err }
    as -> errs
  }
}
```

The type isn't quite the same as the one you proposed, but it's unclear why you would want a list of pairs of lists, so I simplified it to a pair of lists.

Comment: Can't understand how it works. `transform` takes two labdas and doesn't have default value. You added one lambda and it' works.

Comment: There are two different versions of `transform`. One of them takes two parameters, the other one takes only one. https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/concurrent/Future.html#transform

Comment: Yes, but the second one takes `Try` (`transform[S](f: (Try[T]) => Try[S])`), but we have `future` in your code.

Comment: No, I think you're confusing `traverse` and `transform`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Await`:
https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.3/scala/concurrent/Await$.html

```
import scala.concurrent.Await
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.util.Try

val res = Try(Await.result(someFuture, 10.seconds))
```

That said, blocking is rarely a good idea. Futures are meant to be composed with methods such as `flatMap`.

Comment: Yes. But I need something like `Future.sequnce`. I have to convert `List<Future<A>>` to `Future<List<(List<A>, List<Throwable>)>>`. I don't know how to do it without blocking.